# Spring maven in sts

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I have the following problem, that's confusing me I would really appreciate your help:
the problem is that when i downloaded the jars i need in the web-inf/lib directory my project works perfectly

I'm using STS (maven, spring, hibernate)

here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/DisplayAll",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String DisplayAll( Model model){
    model.addAttribute("emPloye",employe.getAllEmploye());
return "Employe";}
```

in my jsp

```
 <form action="DisplayAll.do" method="get" onsubmit="show();">
<input type="submit" value="Afficher Tous Les Employes" />
</form></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<center><table border="1" bordercolor="blue" width="90%" id="myTable" > 
<tr id='tr1'>
<th>NSS     </th>
<th>Nom     </th>
<th>Prenom  </th>
<th>Date De Naissance   </th> 
<th>Lieu de Naissance   </th>
<th>Adresse</th>
<th>Tel     </th>
<th>Poste    </th>
</tr>
<tr >
<td >${e.nss}</td>
<td>${e.nom}</td>
<td>${e.prenom}</td>
<td>${e.dateDeNaissance}</td> 
<td>${e.lieuDeNaissance}</td>
<td>${e.adresse} </td>
<td>${e.tel} </td>
<td>${e.poste} </td>
<td> <a href="deleteEmp.do?nss=${e.nss}"><img src="del.gif" width=35 height=35></a></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

now to the results i get:

**when I use Maven I get : the word  Employe in a blak page**

**when I directly paste the jars I need in lib folder, I get the list of employes I'm looking for**
I really need to use maven since it's not gd to everytime download the jar & copy it manually,

Just to let you know the pom file contains the dependencies of the jars i downloaded manually (all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `@ResponseBody` annotation, you are telling spring that the string you are returning is the actual HTML that will be displayed. If you want to show your jsp you will need to return a view name. If what you're returning ("Employe") is the view name, just get rid of the @ResponseBody annotation and it should work.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked, but I would like to ask you a question, why I got the problem while using maven but not when i directly copied the jars in lib directory! I didn't change anything in the code ..Best regards

Comment: I'm not positive about that. My guess would be that when you copied the jars, they didn't register and the @ResponseBody annotation wasn't interpreted. But that really is just a guess. By the way if the answer worked, please accept it.